# java,how to consult sql lite if a value of a variable "varConsult" is in column "protocolo" in table "pessoajuridica",

Tags: java, sql

i tryed this:

```
ResultSet existetabela = stm.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM pessoajuridica WHERE protocolo ="  + varConsult ); 
System.out.println(existetabela);
```

but it only return a strange String -> org.sqlite.RS@1f959518

i was expecting the value..

remembering, sql lite and java :S

i want to use the value that it return to compare, if it return any value, means that it exist, so it will not add to the sql, if dont return anything = can add!!!

("if exist" doesnt work for me, says that its a invalid argument in the sql command line --')

Comment: You have a SQL injection issue with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate inside the result set to retrive the actual data that were found:

```
while (existetabela.next()){
 System.out.println(existetabela.getObject("protocolo"));
}
```

Did you look at [**PreparedStatement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ResultSet#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) method to test whether there was any result set returned:

```
if (existetabela.next()) {
    // Result was fetched
    // Assuming type of protocol is String (Can be anything)
    String protocol = existetabela.getString("protocolo");

} else {
    // No result
}
```

Now, let's move ahead to the major issue. You should use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), to save yourself from [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: thanks worked like a charm, and i will study more about the injection